# What is good UI tools/library for browsing database table in web application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In this case, column size/names of a given table varies according to the table selected. What would be a good tool or library for that? I would also appreciate if you can point to any open source project doing this.

Comment: SSMS is not good enough?

Comment: We need to provide a UI for user to browse before select columns. I don't think we can ask users to look at SSMS.

Comment: Look for example on PHPMyAdmin. It uses standard html inputs. You don't need specialized components. Since jQuery is strongly used in ASP.NET MVC, you can think about using jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/) for general look and effects and to handle special types of fields (for example dates).

Comment: Yeah, I was going to look at PHPMyAdmin page anyway. I don't have any problem with using jquery. I was little worried on variable columns. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/queryexplus/

Comment: That would be useful for me anyway but my question was on UI libraries/tools for browsing in a web application. But thanks anyway.

Comment: You can read the table schemas from systables and just spit them out as HTML tables if you want something simple.

Comment: You may want to query information_schema.tables and display the reslts on UI in a grid.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will follow your suggestions.